# Hide element on checkbox click/check, re-insert element on checkbox uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im learning Jquery so please bear with me here I would like to hide / remove a `DIVs` content if a checkbox is check>

When checkbox is **unchecked** **I would like the `DIVs` content to re-appear**,(which was hidden on checkbox checked.)

I have managed to solve part 1 of the problem, hiding the content but Im stuck on getting content re-appear.

[YOU CAN VIEW MY JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/leela89/x44fjg7j/)

Any help appreciated

Comment: how much check box do you have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('.return_to_pickup_location').click(function() { //fire when the button is clicked
        $('form input:checkbox').each(function() {
          var checkbox = $(this);  
          if(checkbox.is(':checked')) 
             $('.returnLocation').hide("slow");
          else
            $('.returnLocation').show("slow");

        });
    });
});
```

Just add show to the element in else block.

Answer (score 1):

If you have single checkbox no need to have for each loop

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x44fjg7j/2/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#return_to_pickup_location').click(function() { //fire when the button is clicked
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        $('.returnLocation').hide("slow");
    else
        $('.returnLocation').show("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have done coding on only if condition try to add else condition also to get your required result like below code

```
$(function() {
    $('.return_to_pickup_location').click(function() { //fire when the button is clicked
        $('form input:checkbox').each(function() {
          var checkbox = $(this);  
          if(checkbox.is(':checked')) $('.returnLocation').hide("slow");
          else
      $('.returnLocation').show("slow");
        });
    });
});
```